# Error java.lang.StackOverflowError - Gradle, al seleccionar proyecto en Eclipse Oxigen

Tags: gradle, eclipse-oxygen

¡Buen día a todos!

Estoy trabajando con Gradle actualmente, el problema es que al momento de querer seleccionar un proyecto para realizar cualquier tarea desde la vista **Gradle Task**, pareciera que se vuelve "loquito" ya trata por si solo de seleccionar todos los proyectos al mismo tiempo, y finalmente me arroja este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente que le doy **ok**, me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que aunque reinicie por completo mi IDE, continua apareciendo el error. Ya actualicé el Gradle pero el problema persiste.

Si alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo y pudiera orientarme, se lo agradecería mucho.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Creo que ayudaria poner el build.gradle en la pregunta

Comment: La verdad no creo que el problema sea el build.gradle, ya que si corro una tarea gradle desde el explorador de proyectos sobre un componente, lo hace sin problemas. O podrías decirme a que tipo de error te refieres o porque crees que sea necesario compartir mi build.gradle, si lo es para compartirlo.

Comment: Sigues teniendo este error?

Comment: Que tal @JonathanJohx, si aun sigo con este problema en eclipse.

Comment: @YSCGProJ intentaste eliminar el .metada folder que esta dentro del workspace?

Comment: Ya intente con eso, pero solo me limpio el workspace, y tuve que volver a importar todos mis proyectos pero al final resulta el mismo error!

Comment: Ok, intentaste reinstalar @YSCGProJ? La manera forzosamente de hacer, si no estoy mal es una versión antigua tu eclipse verdad?

Comment: La versión que tengo es la 3, y en efecto no lo he reinstalado, probaré haciéndolo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacer la instalación nuevamente, fue la solución.